# How can I turn this 'V' shaped indent into a smooth rounded indent with a smooth join

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]

How can I turn this 'V' shaped indent into a smooth rounded indent(Blue) with a smooth join(Red)

Comment: Hello do you have a reference image that would help to understand the shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u used bevel to create that indent, you can tweak the settings of it right after you did it to make the bevel more round instead of V shaped. By increasing the segments and tweaking the shape parameter for example.

If you didn't use a bevel and want to change the shape to be more round, i'd suggest you merge the vertices back together so you have one line of edges, and apply a bevel again with the right shape.
If that's not possible, you could try manually adding edges with the loop cut tool and tweak them accordingly.